# Getting sketchy looking diagrams with Microsoft Office suite?

Tags: windows, microsoft-office, diagrams

From what I know, the following picture was created in Key Note:

http://github.com/downloads/nvie/gitflow/Git-branching-model.PDF

I'd like to know if is it possible to get this sketchy style in some way with the Microsoft Office suite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, at least not from the out of box experience. But it may be possible to find (or create) an add-in that does a similar thing.

On closer inspection of the PDF, it looks like the arrows etc are all the same (rather complex/detailed) vector image, that are just scaled/rotated as needed. Perhaps if you could find the source vector images you could import them into office in a similar fashion to clipart.

Comment: Hmmmm. Nice idea!

Comment: It might be possible to somehow extract the vector information from the PDF, either directly, or as a screenshot etc and then converting it.